# How to solve the ambiguous type variable error in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to implement the following function to calculate $(-1)^n / (2n + 1)$ for an integer $n$ in Julia into Haskell.

```
# Julia

powersign(n) = ifelse(n % 2 == 0, 1, -1)

leibniz_term(n) = powersign(n) / (2n + 1)

println(leibniz_term(10)) # 0.047619047619047616
```

I write

```hs
-- Haskell

powersign 0 = 1
powersign 1 = -1
powersign n = powersign (rem n 2)

leibniz_term n = (powersign n) / (2 * n + 1)

main = print (leibniz_term 10)
```

but this gives the following errors.

```
$ ghc -o leibniz_hs leibniz.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( leibniz.hs, leibniz.o )

leibniz.hs:9:8: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus 13 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: print (leibniz_term 10)
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = print (leibniz_term 10)
  |
9 | main = print (leibniz_term 10)
  |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
```

Probably, I need to add type annotations to somewhere but I don't know how to do it.
How to modify the code to work correctly?

Comment: It is recommended to provide a type signature for each definition - that will produce better error messages. Also, turn on warnings, and try to respect them.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `rem` works for `Integer`-like numbers, so `powersign` should be applied to those (In haskell named `Integral` type class). Whereas, division `(/)` is real number division. The compiler cannot know if `n` in `leibniz_term` is Integer-like or Real-like. In haskell you should explicitly convert between number types.

```
powersign 0 = 1
powersign 1 = -1
powersign n = powersign (rem n 2)

leibniz_term n = fromIntegral (powersign n) / (2 * fromIntegral n + 1)

main = print (leibniz_term 10)
```

#### Haskell's Numerical Hierarchy uncomplete history

In haskell you have regular number types: `Int`, `Integer`, `Float` and `Double`

All of them instantiate the `Num` Type Class. Meaning that they can perform

```
(+), (-), (*), signum, negate, ... (and some others)
```

Then division is different, you have `Integral` Type class to perform integer division: `quot, rem, etc...`. Members of this type class are `Int` and `Integer`

And `Fractional` type class to perform real-number divison: `/`. Members of this type class are `Float` and `Double`

To perform math operations like `cos`, `sin`, `log`, etc... you Have the `Floating` type class which members are `Float` and `Double`

Coercion is done via `fromIntegral`, which transform `Int` and `Integer` to any other numerical type. Transforming from `Double` or `Float` back to `Integral` is done using common `truncate`, `ceiling`, etc...

You have another numerical type called `Rational`, which is literally a ration between `Intergers`. There are some other numerical classes like `RealFrac`, `RealFloat`. You can get more info here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Converting_numbers and https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html

Comment: So `/` for integers (they are real numbers) is not division as real numbers (in Julia) but integer quotient  (in Haskell)?

Comment: @Paalon no. The operator `/` is not defined for Integers. If you type `:t (/)` in GHCi you'll see that the type signature is `(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`, meaning that `/` is defined for type which implements the `Fractional` type class. if you type `:i Int` you'll see that `Int` nor `Integer` have `Fractional` instances. Let me edit the question, to add more info about this